# Use of stackexchange data in commercial publication

Tags: discussion, support, licensing

I am writing a book about search engines. I'm hunting for a data set to drive examples throughout the book. I'd like to use data derived from stackexchange (via the API) and I want to make sure that I am in the clear to do so.

I basically intend to:

- Take the data (posts, tags, etc), chew on it, put it into a search engine (ie Elasticsearch)
- Iterate on the data, possibly muck with it to improve the relevance of the search results, showing off useful techniques and strategies
- Possibly quote brief snippets as parts of the search

The book is for-profit if that is relevant to the discussion. Though I'm not exactly going to making anything significant, I'm in this to write the book, not make money.

Seems this discussion is relevant. Which seems close to what I'm doing, though my publication is not academic.

I think I am covered by CC-by-sa, but licensing is fairly confusing to me and I want to make sure the book itself would not be considered a derrived work just by using an open data set :)